# Can not access array with valid key in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, phalcon

When I try to see actual keys of array with:

```
dd(array_keys($this->credentials));
```

it shows me following:

```
Array (4) (
  [0] => String (7) "*data"
  [1] => String (14) "*insensitive"
  [2] => String (12) "*lowerKeys"
  [3] => String (16) "*pathDelimiter"
)
```

But when I try to access the keys listed here like

```
dd($this->credentials['*data']);
```

or

```
dd($this->credentials['data']);
```

it returns `Null`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance)

Edit:

The issue was about converting object to array in my case. In old versions of PHP I have done it like

```
$this->credentials = (array) $this->config->smth->{$key};
```

Which is not working in 7.4 ($this->config returns object).
I needed to change it to

```
$this->credentials = $this->config->smth->{$key}->toArray();
```

But still can anyone explain what exactly changed in new version.

Comment: What is the result of a var_dump on $this->credentials ?

Comment: @svgta multidimensional array. I can see all its keys and values but cant access them. All returning Null.

Comment: Which is the result of `print_r($this->credentials)`? And of `Phalcon\Helper\Arr::get($this->credentials, 'data')`? Also, could there be any conflict between a method or service with the same name as var `credentials` in the class?

Comment: `String (7) "*data"` Note this is not a 7 character long string. You appear to have some multibyte and/or unprintable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `$this->credentials` is a converted object/class?
If so, the asterisk means that those were private properties.

Comment: The asterisk in front indicates that it is a protected/private property, so you can't access them